# Vuetify nested data table alignments

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetify-datatable

I have got a [vuetify data table](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/) with [expandable rows](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#expandable-rows). When expanded, I want to show a data table within the expanded section that has the exact same columns as the main one. I am having trouble with aligning the columns, I just can't seem to align them.

I have tried adding another data table within the parent one, adding a full `<table>` or only `<tr>`s and/or `<td>`s but no luck.

The result so far is

[image: nested tables]

You can see that the nested table is not aligned with the parent one, the figures are out of place.

Here is where I got so far ([CodePen](https://codepen.io/chiapa/pen/YzEexwp?editors=1010)):

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="reportData"
      :items-per-page="-1"
      :single-expand="false"
      :expanded.sync="expanded"
      class="elevation-1"
      show-expand
      item-key="id" 
    >
      <template v-slot:top>
        <v-toolbar flat>
          <v-toolbar-title>Report</v-toolbar-title>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        </v-toolbar>
      </template>

      <template v-slot:expanded-item="{ headers, item }">
        <td :colspan="headers.length">
          <table style="width: 100%;">
            
            <tr v-for="row in item.events" :key="row.id">

              <td v-if="key != 'id'" v-for="(event, key) in row">{{row[key]}}</td>
              
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

And

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      expanded: [],
      singleExpand: false,
      headers: [
        { text: 'Event Name', value: 'name'},
            { text: 'Total Hits', value: 'totalHits' },
            { text: 'Unique Hits', value: 'uniqueHits' },
            { text: '', value: 'data-table-expand' },
      ],
      reportData: [
    {
        "id": 294,
        "name": "Bounce",
        "totalHits": 40243,
        "uniqueHits": 14569,
        "events": [
            {
                "id": 411,
                "name": "Bounce",
                "totalHits": 40242,
                "uniqueHits": 14568
            },
            {
                "id": 562,
                "name": "",
                "totalHits": 1,
                "uniqueHits": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 295,
        "name": "Return",
        "totalHits": 1763,
        "uniqueHits": 672,
        "events": [
            {
                "id": 412,
                "name": "Return",
                "totalHits": 1628,
                "uniqueHits": 623
            },
            {
                "id": 417,
                "name": "Push",
                "totalHits": 135,
                "uniqueHits": 49
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 402,
        "name": "Deadly Virus | Push",
        "totalHits": 69,
        "uniqueHits": 28,
        "events": [
            {
                "id": 561,
                "name": "No Action Needed",
                "totalHits": 69,
                "uniqueHits": 28
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 404,
        "name": "Returns",
        "totalHits": 17124,
        "uniqueHits": 2762,
        "events": [
            {
                "id": 409,
                "name": "Not a candidate",
                "totalHits": 5613,
                "uniqueHits": 384
            },
            {
                "id": 557,
                "name": "Sold Out",
                "totalHits": 11511,
                "uniqueHits": 2378
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 405,
        "name": "Deadly Virus | Push < Stage 1",
        "totalHits": 20,
        "uniqueHits": 16,
        "events": [
            {
                "id": 559,
                "name": "Unknow Source Added",
                "totalHits": 20,
                "uniqueHits": 16
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 411,
        "name": "Bad Test",
        "totalHits": 159,
        "uniqueHits": 103,
        "events": [
            {
                "id": 421,
                "name": "Yes",
                "totalHits": 9,
                "uniqueHits": 7
            },
            {
                "id": 568,
                "name": "No",
                "totalHits": 150,
                "uniqueHits": 96
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 462,
        "name": "New AMR",
        "totalHits": 1,
        "uniqueHits": 1,
        "events": [
            {
                "id": 623,
                "name": "Completed",
                "totalHits": 1,
                "uniqueHits": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 472,
        "name": "Deadly Virus  | Push >Stage 1",
        "totalHits": 690,
        "uniqueHits": 159,
        "events": [
            {
                "id": 561,
                "name": "No Action Needed",
                "totalHits": 690,
                "uniqueHits": 159
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 473,
        "name": "Deadly Virus | Push < Stage 1 | Unknow Source Added",
        "totalHits": 75,
        "uniqueHits": 69,
        "events": [
            {
                "id": 559,
                "name": "Unknow Source Added",
                "totalHits": 75,
                "uniqueHits": 69
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 488,
        "name": "Inadequate",
        "totalHits": 7,
        "uniqueHits": 7,
        "events": [
            {
                "id": 623,
                "name": "Boom",
                "totalHits": 7,
                "uniqueHits": 7
            }
        ]
    }
],
      
    }
  },
})
```

**EDIT**

I got to the solution based on @Oleg's answer. Thanks @Oleg.

```
<td v-for="header in headers">
    <div class="use-case-breakdown-container">
        <div class="use-case-breakdown" v-for="actionObj in item.actions" :key="actionObj.id">
           <div v-for="prop in Object.keys(actionObj)">
             <span v-if="prop == header.value">
               {{actionObj[header.value]}}
             </span>
           </div>         
        </div>
    </div>
 </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it with `CSS Grid` and without nesting tables ([Codepen](https://codepen.io/olegnaumov/pen/ExbQopP)):

```
  <template v-slot:expanded-item="{ headers, item }">
    <td v-for="(header, parent_index) in headers">
      <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-item" v-for="row in item.events" :key="row.id">
          <div v-for="(value, event, child_index) in row">
            <span v-if="parent_index + 1 === child_index"> {{ value }}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
   </template>
```

And CSS:

```
.grid-container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of using divs and spans only

Comment: You're welcome. The real trick was not `CSS Grid` actually, it was to loop the top `<td>` tag instead of using `<td :colspan="headers.length">` as a wrapper for the data.

Comment: I got to the solution. I've updated the question with it. Thanks